# Two different ways to interpret "The problem is not that you have an ugly face."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> A: Nobody wants to date me. It is all because I have an ugly face.

> B: **The problem is not that you have an ugly face**. The problem is that you are too straightforward.

To me, there are two different ways to interpret the bolded part.

**Interpretation A:**

You don't have an ugly face, which implies an ugly face could be a problem.

**Interpretation B:**

Yes, you do have an ugly face, but that is not the problem.

---

Do you guys think there are different ways to interpret the bolded part? If yes, why are there different ways to look at it?

Comment: I agree that there are different ways to interpret it.  As for *why* there are different ways to look at it, I think it depends on what kind of answer you are looking for.  At one level, we could just say "Because human languages always have some ambiguity."

Comment: Yes, there are different ways to interpret it. However, as a guy, you never want to say sentences like this, because even if you meant A, the woman will think you meant B.

Comment: As a university student who had solved a particularly difficult problem in class, I was approached by a fellow student who said: "I don't understand the solution." To this, I replied: "I'm not surprised, meaning that I'd found it extremely difficult....... As Felinius says!